# Debugging session breaks with no breakpoint

Tags: c#, debugging, breakpoints, visual-studio-2012, ccr

I have a large project that executes without problem when not debugging (even when running the debug build).

If I try to debug the project, when execution hits a certain MS CCR dependent library the debugger pauses execution:

[image: disassembly of source]

The call stack at this point appears as follows:

[image: stack trace]

This occurs even when "Debug"->"Exceptions..."->"CLR Exceptions" *thrown* **and** *user-unhandled* are both unchecked.

The problem appears to be happening in `Microsoft.Core.Ccr.dll` at `Microsoft.Ccr.Core.TaskExecutionWorker.ExecuteTaskHelper(Microsoft.Ccr.Core.ITask currentTask) + 0x94 bytes` since I upgraded the project to .net4.5 and added the latest version of `Microsoft.Ccr.Core` (4.0.261.0).

This is a major inconvenience to my debugging efforts as hitting these non-existent breakpoints means that other time-related parts of my project are almost impossible to debug correctly.

What could possibly be causing this behaviour and are there any options I've missed that might allow VS to ignore the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) decompilation of `TaskExecutionWorker.ExecuteTaskHelper` I see the following:

```
    if (!CausalityThreadContext.IsEmpty(threadCausalities) && 
         CausalityThreadContext.RequiresDebugBreak(threadCausalities))
      Debugger.Break();
```

I can see why they did this (I have unhandled exceptions somewhere) but now they've been gobbled by CCR, and the info I can see in the debugger makes this code-defined breakpoint somewhat pointless.

EDIT

It seems that I had added Causalities with property `BreakOnReceive = true` to the Dispatcher. As such this is expected behaviour. I can't see any possible use for this setting as the exceptions have been gobbled. Surely a better decision here would be to throw an exception rather than break the debugger. Hmmm...